# Reshaping array with specified indices

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, reshape

Is there any better way to do this? Like replacing that list comprehension with numpy functions? I'd assume that for a small number of elements, the difference is insignificant, but for larger chunks of data it takes too much time.

```
>>> rows = 3
>>> cols = 3
>>> target = [0, 4, 7, 8] # each value represent target index of 2-d array converted to 1-d
>>> x = [1 if i in target else 0 for i in range(rows * cols)]
>>> arr = np.reshape(x, (rows, cols))
>>> arr 
[[1 0 0]
 [0 1 0]
 [0 1 1]]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `x` comes from a range, you can index an array of zeros to set the ones:

```
x = np.zeros(rows * cols, dtype=bool)
x[target] = True
x = x.reshape(rows, cols)
```

Alternatively, you can create the proper shape up front and assign to the raveled array:

```
x = np.zeros((rows, cols), dtype=bool)
x.ravel()[target] = True
```

If you want actual zeros and ones, use a dtype like `np.uint8` or whatever else suits your needs other than `bool`.

The approach shown here would apply even to your list example to make it more efficient. Even if you turned `target` into a `set`, you are performing `O(N)` lookups, with `N = rows * cols`. Instead, you only need `M` assignments with no lookups, with `M = len(target)`:

```
x = [0] * (rows * cols)
for i in target:
    x[i] = 1
```

Answer (score 4):

Another way:

```
shape = (rows, cols)
arr = np.zeros(shape)
arr[np.unravel_index(target, shape)] = 1
```

Comment: Generally more robust than `x.ravel()[target] = True`, although with a freshly allocated `x`, my version is likely a tad faster.